# Localhost:4200 on phone

Tags: angular, git, localhost, git-bash

I have been trying to open localhost:4200 on my android phone.

My project is in Angular 4 and I work with GIT Bash.

I tried with these commands:

```
npm start --host 0.0.0.0
npm start --host 192.168.1.7
npm start --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
npm start --host 192.168.1.7 --disable-host-check
```

The project starts and this parts run smoothly, no matter which command.

But when I try to open my project as

```
192.168.1.7:4200
```

or

```
localhost:4200
```

It says: **This site can’t be reached**

I turned off my firewalls, I checked my IP address in command prompt with *ipconfig* and under IPv4 Address is that address. My phone and my laptop are connected to the same WiFi network, but what I noticed is that my laptop says the IP address is 192.168.1.7 and my phone says 192.168.1.4, either way, I tried both, even in the command in bash.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all devices are on same network

- first use `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
- get your ip from ipconfig
- go to `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall` in control panel
- click `Turn Windows defender firewall on or off` appearing on left panel
- select turn off for all 3 settings and click ok at bottom
- not your app should be available on other devices . use `ip:4200` or in your case `192.168.1.7:4200`

I also faced same problem but my resolution was point 4 mentioned above. so please try this

Comment: thank you for your answer! All devices are connected to the same network. When I use ng serve I get an error since my project start with npm start and the error is \AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

Comment: then add a script in package.json-> you will find `"start": "ng serve"` replace it with `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"`

Comment: this worked! Thank you very much! I got the **Invalid Host Header** error too, but I fixed it with adding `--disable-host-check`. Thanks again!